# LayerDrawable - circle in circle programmatically

Tags: java, android

i am trying to create a dynamic Drawable with LayerDrawable class. My final purpose is to create such a Drawable based on database interogation. Let's say that I have 5 entries into database my Drawable will contain 5 inner circles with different colors. I managed to make it work with an xml file, but i would like to create it dynamically by java code. Maybe a better approach would be to set a maximum of let's say 5 circles and just change the colors based on input? What are your opinions here?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item>

    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:top="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp">

    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/caldroid_light_red"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:top="8dp"
    android:right="8dp"
    android:bottom="8dp"
    android:left="8dp">

    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:top="16dp"
    android:right="16dp"
    android:bottom="16dp"
    android:left="16dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I can't manage to undestand the setLayerInset function. From documentation i understood that the largest number will be placed on the top. This means that for my case i need to shrink each circle for each iteration. Example code below

```
 int value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            5, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    for (ElementGroup element:databaseInsertions){
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();

        OvalShape oval = new OvalShape();
        gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        gradientDrawable.setColor(R.color.colorPrimary);

        gradientDrawable.setStroke(value, Color.WHITE);

        listOfCircles[dynamic] = gradientDrawable;
        dynamic++;
    }

    LayerDrawable circle = new LayerDrawable(listOfCircles);
    int width = tileWidth;
    int part = tileWidth / listOfCircles.length;
    for(int index = 0; index<listOfCircles.length;index++){

        circle.setLayerInset(index, width,width,width,width);
        width-=part;

    }
```

Comment: use a custom `Shape` class. override its `draw` method and pass it to a `ShapeDrawable` constructor

Comment: Shape is not a problem, i can create the Shape, layering side is not working for me.

Comment: so create a custom `Shape` class and draw what you want in `draw` method

Comment: the base implementation would be like [this](http://pastebin.com/NC52H1KT), and the usage: `Drawable d = new ShapeDrawable(new S(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GRAY));`

Comment: I am working on implementation. I will return with the output. Thanks!

Comment: I finished, decided to go with xml file reference with 5 items on layer_list. Based on input from database I change the stroke color. For the moment i will use this. I will try in the future to implement as you sugested. Thanks

Comment: why do you want 6 drawables instead of just one? (LayerDrawable + 5 GradientDrawables), it will be not only more complex solution but also will take more memory and will be slower than using just one custom drawable, what is unclear in those 20 lines of custom `Shape`?

Comment: Hello pskink, you were right, i implemented as you sugested and is much easier to adapt to other scenarios. Thanks alot!

Comment: your welcome, now you will know how to make some complex shapes without writing dozens of xml drawables...